# Can I automatically fix my old paths to tests in Intellij IDEA(using IDEA tools)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I change paths to java classes in gradle project, but paths for this classes tests steel the same.

Can I change paths using IDEA tools, not manually?

[paths to classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vraI9.png)

[paths to tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8nIC.png)

Comment: What kind of project setup do you have exactly? Maven build? Gradle Build? Plain IDEA project?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the changes? Can you revert these changes and do Refactor | Rename in IntelliJ IDEA again so that it updates the classes and usages in tests automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Project is Gradle Build

Comment: Can you run the tests with gradle? IDEA should automatically reload the gradle configuration for the source sets and you need to make the gradle build work anyways, otherwise it is useless that you put effort into the gradle config at all.

Comment: I try to ran build and rebuild, but it not help

[paths to classes][1]

  [1]: https://prnt.sc/p_M3TXuyh7xB